# Vue Component property type for different childs

Tags: typescript, vue-component, vuejs3

I have a vue 3 component with two properties. The first property is the v-model and the second is the type. Depending on the type my component should be a simple input or a select box with multiple selections. The v-model for the simple input is a string and for the select it is an array.
When I want to use the component as select and assign an array to the v-model I get the TypeScript `Error 2322`

```
Type 'string | number | array ' is not assignable to type 'string | number | null | undefined'.
Type 'array' is not assignable to type 'string | number | null | undefined'.ts(2322)
```

I can't change the type of InputComponent because it is a ready component

Has someone a solution that I can choose between input and select, I dont't want to make two separate components

Parent Component

```
<template>
    <ExampleComponent v-model="example" select-box></ExampleComponent>
</template>
```

ExampleComponent template

```
<template>
         <div class="component-wrapper-with-stylings">
        <InputComponent v-if="!select-box" v-model="modelValueCopy" />
        <SelectComponent v-if="select-box" v-model="modelValueCopy" />
        </div>
    </template>
```

ExampleComponent script

```
<script setup lang="ts">
    const emit = defineEmits(['update:modelValue'])
    
    const props = defineProps({
        modelValue: {
            type: [String, Number, Array ],
            required: true
        },
        selectBox: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: false
        }
    })
    
    const modelValueCopy = computed({
    get () {
        return props.modelValue
    },
    set (value) {
        return emit('update:modelValue', value)
    }
})
</script>
```

Creating two components works but it is not that what I want

Answer (score 0):

The `v-if` condition should use `selectBox`, not `select-box`.

```
 <input v-if="!selectBox" v-model="modelValueCopy" />
 <select v-if="selectBox" v-model="modelValueCopy" />
```

Without TypeScript you code works well.

Here is the [SFC Playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

With TypeScript either: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-66mzhc?file=src/components/ExampleComponent.vue)

But it does not make any sense, what you are trying to achieve.
Since, passing the options for select inside the modelValue, which is bound using `v-model` will not work.

Or I didn't get it right.

Comment: In my code I have the v-if like you wrote it, but it is irrelevant for my problem.
I have to and I want to use typescript. No typescript isn't an option.
I want to have only one component for an input, a select or a multiselect. The v-model is a string when the component is an input, a string when the component is a select or an array when the component is a multiselect. The Problem is the v-model of the input child, which can only be string, number, null or undefined